# "Relevance" feature not enabled in "techproducts" example shipped with solr 6.4

Tags: solr

I am using "techproducts" default example shipped with solr 6.4 which used velocity template.
I am searching for keyword "ipod with" without double quotes and it returns one result which is exact match.Other 2 results which have keyword "ipod" are not returned.
How do i enable relevancy in the default "techproducts" example shipped with solr 6.4

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Your default operator might have changed to AND, make it OR.  add `q.op` parameter to URL

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection_name/select?indent=on&q=ipod with&wt=json&q.op=OR
```

Comment: How do I set this in the config file so that after searching for " ipod with" on the UI I get the expected result.Below is the default UI for techproducts for solr.http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/browse?&q=ipod%20with

Comment: If I make config changes permanently I do not have to accordingly change my query URL.How do I achieve relevancy so that first result is  "ipod with" which is exact match and rest two are "ipod" based on relevancy

Comment: In schema file you can set <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/> , which is deprecated. You are using Solritas which is example UI application comes by default.  You need to check temple files where query URL is formed, and set q.op=OR. I guess its query.vm/query_form.vm is the file you should check for.

Comment: I made the below changes to solrconfig.xml....In  <!-- Query settings -->changed  <str name="mm">100%</str> to  <str name="mm">1%</str>.. A value of 1 means only one term from the query must match (same behavior as OR).A value of 100% mean all the terms must match (same behavior as AND). changing the value from 100 to 1 and restarting solr worked.Thanks for your help..